# von Mises-Fisher distributions and Gauss characterization of Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, mean, von-mises-distribution

We can read in Jaynes' *Probability Theory: The Logic of Science* that the family of Gaussian densities
$$ f_{m}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$
with $m\in \mathbb{R}$ is the only translation invariant family such that the MLE of $m$ for iid samples is the empirical mean:
$$ \hat m_{MLE} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i.$$

The von Mises-Fisher distribution on the sphere is defined as
$$f(x) = C e^{\kappa \mu^T x} $$
with $\kappa>0$ and $\|\mu\|=1$. $\mu$ can be interpreted as a mean parameter and $\kappa$ as the inverse of the variance. This family is not translation invariant in the original sense, but is invariant under the action of $SO(n)$. Furthermore, the MLE of $\mu$ for iid samples is the normalized empirical mean
$$ \hat \mu_{MLE} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i}{\|\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i\|}.$$
Do we also have a result saying that the von Mises-Fisher densities with fixed $\kappa$ are the only family invariant by the action of $SO(n)$ such that the MLE is the normalized sample mean?

Comment: Which property? Translation invariance??

Comment: As this question is purely mathematical (probability theory), I think it should be migrated to the math SE.

Comment: I am happy with a mathematical question about probability distributions, which is relevant statistically. There is just the detail of what the question is about;,

Comment: @NickCox, the property is that the MLE of the mean and the (renormalized-)sample mean coinincide.

Comment: There's a little ambiguity here, but evidently the corresponding property would be invariance under a transitive group of isometries of the sphere.  The natural candidates are the orthogonal group $O(n)$ and special orthogonal group $SO(n),$ but others are possible.

Comment: @whuber, I edited the question based on your comment.